# Getting pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError no matter what

Tags: python, mongodb, exception, pymongo

Im trying to connect with MongoDB Atlas using motor and asyncio, but i keep get the ServerSelectionTimetoutError.

```
import asyncio
import motor.motor_asyncio
import urllib


class DBManager:
def __init__(self):
    self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    self.client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb://500PlusClient:TopSecretPassword@500plus-shard-00-00-1kawz.azure.mongodb.net:27017,500plus-shard-00-01-1kawz.azure.mongodb.net:27017,500plus-shard-00-02-1kawz.azure.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=500Plus-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority", io_loop=self.loop)

async def insert_to_database(self, product):
    await self.client.ProjektProducts.produkty.insert_one(product)

async def get_products(self):
    db = self.client.test
    collection = db.products
    object = await collection.find_one({"song": "Young Thug - Relationship"})
    for objects in object:
        print(objects)

def update_products(self):
    collection = self.client.test.products
    collection.update_one({'song': 'exampletitle'}, {"$set": {'is_awesome': "indeed"}})


db = DBManager()
db.loop.run_until_complete(db.get_products())
db.loop.close()
```

Comment: Can you connect using the same connection string via the mongo shell, e.g. `$ mongo mongodb://500PlusClient:TopSecretPassword@500plus-shard-00-00-1kawz.azure.mongodb.net:27017,500plus-shard-00-01-1kawz.azure.mongodb.net:27017,500plus-shard-00-02-1kawz.azure.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=500Plus-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority` ?

Comment: I can't, im getting "Server selection timed out after 30000 ms"

Comment: OK then at least you know the issue is not with your python code or pymongo.

Comment: @KamilPaczkowski Have you configured [Whitelist Entries](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/) to allow connections from your server ?

Comment: No, i'll try it.